# Losing solutions to differential equations?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Sometimes we have trivial solutions to differential equations that cannot be obtained from the general solution. Is this always a result of operations such as "dividing both sides by $y$" which excludes $y=0?$ In other words, is it possible to lose solutions without performing operations which put restrictions on $y$?

Answer (score 1):

All solutions of a differential can be obtained from the "general solution", always. That's why we call it "general solution".

On the other hand, if for example if you divide both sides by something the resulting differential equation may not be equivalent to the initial one, and so the set of solutions may change. Something similar happens if you take an even power, take derivatives everywhere, etc.